# Move data from one to the other but with unique mappings

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's hard for me to explain this question but maybe an example helps...

I have two tables, a and b

a is an empty table, it has three columns:

```
id   name  value
```

b is a table that has the same id for a and some other columns and look like this:

```
id    obj_type       obj_status        language
-------------------------------------------------
1     product        operational       English
2     support        operational       French
3     product        non_operational   English
```

Now I want to insert data from table b to a in this way:

```
id    name           value
--------------------------------------
1     obj_type       product
1     obj_status     operational     
1     language       English
2     obj_type       support 
2     obj_status     operational                                         
2     language       French
3     obj_type       product                    
3     obj_status     non_operational                               
3     language       English
```

I wonder if there is way to do it in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT id,'obj_type' as Name, obj_type as Value FROM TableB UNION
SELECT id,'obj_status' as Name,obj_status as Value FROM TableB UNION
SELECT id,'languagee' as Name,  language as Value FROM TableB
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT Column_name FROM Information_schema.columns 
WHERE Table_name ='tableB' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 2) as Name, obj_type as Value FROM tableB UNION
SELECT id,
(SELECT Column_name FROM Information_schema.columns WHERE Table_name ='tableB' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 3) as Name,obj_status as Value FROM tableB UNION
SELECT id,
(SELECT Column_name FROM Information_schema.columns WHERE Table_name ='tableB' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 4) as Name,  _language as Value FROM tableB
ORDER BY id,Name
```